# Ordering and randomizing a query at the same time

Tags: sql, mysql

I need to query my database and partially order and randomize the results.
For instance,

```
SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY views DESC LIMIT 5
```

would result something like this:

```
id   name       views
---------------------
 0   Product #1     2
 1   Product #2     1
 2   Product #3     0
 3   Product #4     0
 4   Product #5     0
```

Now, how can I add RAND() (or something similar) in the query so that the last three items (Products #3, #4 and #5) would appear in random order since they've got the same amount of views, but the first two still descending based on the same views-field?

I tried something like

```
SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY views, RAND() DESC LIMIT 5
```

but obviously it doesn't work.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY views DESC, RAND() LIMIT 5;
```

**maybe** ... you can retrieve the records first then sort randomly using other programming language

Answer (score 0):

i don't know about in mysql, but in sql server you can do `order by newid()`. i'm sure doing the same thing in mysql would work also, i just don't know what the function in mysql is to generate a guid.

Answer (score -1):

Does mysql support `union` and `union all`? I have to imagine it does...

If so, what about something like:

```
SELECT * FROM products where views > 0 ORDER BY views DESC

union all

SELECT * FROM products where views = 0 order by RAND()
```

Obviously your full query may be more complicated and you may need to modify the where clauses to fit your need, but seems like a fairly flexible solution.

Comment: And what if product 3 & 4 have 1 view? The data put on the question is an example only.